# Mongoose Populate with sub-document Id

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have a requirement where I need to add a bunch of countries with associated cities. It will basically be a tree, with the cities being the sub tree of a country node. I have currently implemented it as :

```
var LocationSchema = new Schema({
  country : String,
  cities : [{cityName : String}]
})
```

The advantage I thought was that the city sub-document gets its own _id which I can later use to search and refer in other models.
However currently I have a bunch of models which are as follows :

```
var SomeSchema = new Schema({
  countries : [{type : ObjectId}],
  cities : [{type : ObjectId}]
})
```

The problem comes when I need to populate SomeSchema. Populating Countries is straight forward. However I guess its not possible to do the same with cities. I don't want to have a separate model for cities as then I would need to manage country -> cities or cities -> countries dependencies. Any Idea how else to go about it ?

TLDR :
LocationSchema.. which has cities as a sub-document. I'm using the id generated for this sub-doc in SomeSchema. When I want to populate SomeSchema how do i populate cities ?

Comment: what is the problem you are facing while populating city? How is it different from populating countries? Both are array of `ObjectId`s

Comment: There is no model for cities... In order to use the regular populate I would need a model. And I'm trying to see if I can get away without using a model for cities..

Comment: can you tell about your problem a bit more?

Comment: Also, please tell which shmea are you using currently. From your question, its bit confusing.

Comment: I have locations Schema.. which has cities as a sub-document. I'm using the id generated for this sub-doc in SomeSchema. When I want to populate SomeSchema how do i populate cities ?